# Gitorious installation

Tags: server, failed-installation, gitorious

On : Debian 8 HVM - Gandi Server

Installation procedure :

```
cd /var/tmp

git clone https://git.gitorious.org/gitorious/ce-installer.git && cd ce-installer

./install
```

Result:

```
TASK: [gitorious | enable and start gitorious-http-backend] ******************* 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: service not found: gitorious-http-backend

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/install.retry

localhost                  : ok=31   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1   


+- Oops, a problem occurred.
+- Usually it happens when there's a network problem (probably timeout during package installation).
+- It is safe to run this script again.
```

So, what's wrong?

Comment: do you have a solution now?

Answer (score -1):

I think a problem is with your permission.

Try this:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

And all should be ok.

EDIT:

What is in your error log? Just put that all here.

Comment: The error coming from Ansible (a step not listed in the question) speaks to init not knowing the job name.  Why you'd jump to running a script with sudo permissions is beyond me.